# store and query a book's content by section, online

Tags: digital-asset-management

How do you store an entire book online, with the ability to do the following:

1. query and return a specific chapter, a page, or an example or quiz under a specific topic.
2. make changes to certain segments, ie replace a wrong paragraph, or attach media.
3. attach metadata or attributes to a paragraph, or word in a section of the book.

The books would be in Microsoft Word format (text; I could also convert it to plain text if that would help finding a solution). OS is not a problem, preferably Linux (hosted); the front end would be web based (custom PHP or JS web app).

I have looked at software like DSpace, Eprints and Omeka. I don't understand if they meet my needs; Omeka offers an API but stores single pages as jpeg, so it's not usable.

Are there solutions that manage the digital content in the back end with an API allowing for fetching content into custom front end display in section?

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've integrated the additional details with your question (you can always [edit] it to add/improve on details, which is preferred to comments in cases like this). So let's remove our comments, as they're obsolete now ;) Answers I must leave to others, I don't work with MS formats.

Comment: I don't understand your reply, the format can be any text and include images and videos, what would you recommend for this challenge?

Comment: MSWord is not "plain text", it's a proprietary format. I have no idea how to "vivisect" that the way you'd need it, as I prefer working with open standards. But even with that, I never had such a requirement – so I cannot give any recommendation on this topic. Which is why I wrote, someone else needs to do the answer part – now that we have the requirements straighened out :)

Comment: thanks lzzy. assuming the format was plain text (i can do the conversion), what solution would you recommend.

Comment: As I wrote: I have no recommendation. Not my area of expertise. I was just helping you to add missing facts to the question, to make it easier for others to answer.